# Get information about a video during a streaming, Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

and thank u while reading this question.

I want to get information about a video during a streaming process on my Android device.

I've this Media controller, placed in a VideoView:

```
    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    video.setVideoPath(url);

    ctlr = new MediaController(this);
    ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
    video.setMediaController(ctlr);
    video.start();
```

I wish to get data about the quality of this video and more.

Thank u.